# How to integrate native ios camera SDK in existing react native App?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, camera

I am currently working with a react native app as per requirement i need to integrate external camera with ios and android SDK.

As react native SDK for particular camera is not available can anyone help me with any example how I can complete this task using iOS And Android SDK.

Camera should capture multiple images and video also so that I can post those with button press.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on how you want to take images and videos**

**2 ways possible**

- Simple Approach: (in case default Camera launch)then there are many 3rd party libraries you can integrate. eg: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker#readme
- Since react-native doesn't provide specific camera APIs, you need to write camera-specific code for both IOS and Android separately and connect them.
  You can [refer](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios)

Comment: Thanks Preethi , can you please provide any practical video or example link as I am facing problems while merging native ios SDK as there are multiple files and I do not have any experience with bridging native code to react native App.

Comment: I am using external endoscopic camera with WIFI connection and SDK provided is very rare not getting any sufficient information with This SDK.